# problem with Powershell - sending data with Invoke Web Request

Tags: php, powershell

I have a problem. I am testing various communication channels.

I send a post request with powershell to the server where the php script receives the body and overwrites it in the txt file.

Php server side script:

```
<? Php
$ handle = fopen ("/ path / to / file.txt", "w");
foreach ($ _ POST as $ variable => $ value) {
fwrite ($ handle, $ variable);
fwrite ($ handle, $ value);
fwrite ($ handle, "\ r \ n");
}
fclose ($ handle);
exit;
?>
```

When I send a normal string in the body everything is ok.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost/catch.php -Method Post -Body 'content'
```

When I try to put the command result to my body and send request, I see:

```
$ip = ipconfig
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost/catch.php -Method Post -Body $ip

Invoke-WebRequest: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
At line: 1 char: 1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost/catch.php -M ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest: HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebCmdletWebResponseException, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I tried different methods and conversions but obviously I don't understand something. Please forgive me if the question is obvious - I am a noob.

Any ideas on how to send the output of the powershell command to the server to a php script?
PS. I don't have root on the server. The server is apache. I can configure it via .htaccess

Comment: Try `$ip = ipconfig | Out-String`. Without that, `$ip` is an array of strings

Comment: `$ip = ipconfig | Out-String
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost/catch.php -Method Post -Body $ip`
Invoke-WebRequest : Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That's a different uri you used in the working example...

Comment: Does it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

I ask and answer myself. The server interpreted the query as malicious. I solved this by sending data in json format.

server side:

```
[windrcmm@server163 c2]$ cat json.php
<?php
$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myFile = "json.txt";
file_put_contents($myFile,$jsonString);
echo '{ "success": true }';
?>
```

client side:

```
$ip = ipconfig | Out-String 
$param = @{
    Uri         = "http://localhost/catchjson.php"
    Method      = "Post"
    Body        = $ip
    ContentType = "application/json"
}
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```